# An easy way to create a scatter graph in excel where for a constant x axis, different plots are plotted on different ranges of the x axis

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

I've got a set of data in excel (see picture, sorry if you feel you need the actual .xls spreadsheet, hopefully this is sufficient):

[image]

The first column on the left is the x axis. You can see that each data point is filled. However the many different plots that I would like to plot (each subsequent column after that first column) are plotted on various different ranges of the x axis. Thus far, I haven't found a simple way to plot all plots, I have to select each series manually and select the x and y columns for that series. Is there an easier way, where I can just select the whole data range that I'd like to plot and, if necessary, show the x axis data for it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more fiddling and tweaking I've worked out a way of doing it. I selected the first few columns that only have data for the y-coordinate:

[image]

From there, I was able to create a sensible scatter chart by the normal way of going "insert" tab, "scatter":

[image]

This then creates the movable associated boxes that show x- and y- coordinates, which give me the option of dragging the x- and y- coordinate data to encompass all the data I want quickly and easily:

[image]

I hope this helps someone out there in the same boat as me! If editors can think of a better way to phrase my question so that it is as easy as possible to find, go for it - I can't think of a more technical/objective way of describing what I wanted here...